# How to access IQueryable property after group by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my query to group products by category that is working.

```c-sharp
var products = _db.Products
    .Include(p => p.Category).ToList()
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.CategoryId })
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        CategoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
        Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Price),
        Products = g.ToList()
        //ProductsTest = g.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y.Price)
    });
```

How can I achieve the same without converting products to list after `.Include(p => p.Category)` because I need pagination, sort, etc. for that group?

When I try to run this without `.ToList()` I get the following error:

```c-sharp
The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: new { CategoryId = p.CategoryId }, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
EntityType: Product
ValueBufferExpression: 
    ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
IsNullable: False
.ToList()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

The problem is also the same for the rest of the extension methods: `FirstOrDefault(), First()`...

Does pagination in this case can boost performance or not?

And do I need to use different logic for that or there is something I'm missing? Thanks :)

Comment: So you want to select all the rows and sum them? Yeah, I'd just do the sum in memory.

Comment: Try `AsEnumerable()` or `AsQueryable()`

Comment: No way prior to EF Core 6, `g.ToList()` is non convertible to SQL. Aftert `GroupBy` you cannot access to it's items. EF Core 6 has added this possibility but SQL should be weird. So, better `ToList()` before `GroupBy`.